# Homepage Loading As Index.php

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop

I'm new to prestashop, I had made few changes to the .htaccess now my homepage isn't loading. Whenever i try my domain name it shows the index.php page

[image]

Please, somebody help me. I have tried to re-generate the .htaccess file but was of no use.

Cheers,

AG

Comment: Hello, you see this because your server requests for `.php` files are no passed to `PHP` processor. Sometimes people define PHP processor gateway inside .htaccess files. Did you delete that part?

Comment: What is your .htaccess code now?